# Remake PL/SQL Function for better performance

Tags: sql, function, plsql, query-optimization, oracle-apex

- Can this function be improved for faster loading?

I made this function for **calculating quantities of products per customer** after **deduction of a certain amount of stock in the warehouses** if it exists. This function goes in a View, which is in turn used to **calculate material needs** by another final query, which is displayed in a page in an APEX v19.2 application.

So the page normally took **15 - 20 secs** to load and by adding the function in question as well as a couple of calculations in the View, those are the sum of the warehouses with subqueries and a division of the returned amount from the function (*I will post the View's query as well*), it now takes a minute give or take. **The function:**

```
create or replace FUNCTION fadjust_final_order_qnt(pProd NUMBER)
  RETURN ADJUST_FINAL_ORDER_QNT_OBJ PIPELINED AS

   TYPE cus_n_prods_rec IS RECORD
   (
      cus_id        number
      --product_id    number
   );
   
   TYPE cus_n_prods_tbl IS TABLE OF cus_n_prods_rec;
   
  lcus_n_prods_tbl cus_n_prods_tbl;

  lwrh NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
  SELECT NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN wrh_gr > 0 THEN wrh_gr ELSE 0 END),0) +
             NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN wrh_bg > 0 THEN wrh_bg ELSE 0 END),0)
    INTO lwrh                                                           --  get warehouses
    FROM (
      SELECT
        aop.product_id as prod_id,
        NVL((SELECT SUM(gr.balance) FROM MV_PROD_WH_GR gr, eba_products_mapping mg, eba_cust_products eg
             WHERE gr.fitemgid = mg.gid AND mg.product_id = eg.id AND mg.origin = 'GR' AND eg.id = ecp.id), 0) wrh_gr,
        NVL((SELECT SUM(bg.balance) FROM MV_PROD_WH_BG bg, eba_products_mapping mb, eba_cust_products eb
             WHERE bg.fitemgid = mb.gid AND mb.product_id = eb.id AND mb.origin = 'BG' AND eb.id = ecp.id), 0) wrh_bg,
        (SELECT epcv.descr FROM eba_prod_category_val epcv WHERE epcv.id = ecp.epc_1 AND epcv.epc_id = 1) Production
      FROM APT_ORDERS_PRODUCTS aop
        JOIN APT_ORDERS aor ON aor.id = aop.order_id
        JOIN eba_cust_products ecp ON aop.product_id = ecp.id
        JOIN eba_cust_customers ecc ON aor.cus_id = ecc.id
      WHERE
        ecc.status_id != 5 AND
        --aor.status_id != 24 AND
        aor.created_by NOT IN (4425, 239, 945, 1813, 598) AND
        aor.status_id NOT IN (24, 41) AND
        aor.invoice_number IS NULL AND
        aor.created >= TO_DATE('01/01/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    )
    WHERE Production IS NOT NULL 
    AND prod_id = pProd 
    AND ROWNUM = 1;
    
    select distinct
        cus_id
        --product_id
    BULK COLLECT INTO lcus_n_prods_tbl                        -- For performance
    from(
      SELECT 
        (Select epcv.descr from eba_prod_category_val epcv where epcv.id= ecp.epc_1 and epcv.epc_id=1 ) Production,
        aor.cus_id,
        aop.product_id
      FROM APT_ORDERS_PRODUCTS aop
        JOIN APT_ORDERS aor ON aor.id = aop.order_id
        JOIN eba_cust_products ecp ON aop.product_id = ecp.id
        JOIN eba_cust_customers ecc ON aor.cus_id = ecc.id
      WHERE
        ecc.status_id != 5 
        --AND aor.status_id != 24 
        AND aor.created_by NOT IN (4425, 239, 945, 1813, 598) 
        AND aor.status_id NOT IN (24, 41) 
        AND aor.invoice_number IS NULL 
        AND aor.created >= TO_DATE('01/01/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
       -- AND (SELECT epcv.descr FROM eba_prod_category_val epcv WHERE epcv.id = ecp.epc_1 AND epcv.epc_id = 1) IS NOT NULL 
        )
    where Production is not null
    AND product_id = pProd;

  
  FOR i IN 1 .. lcus_n_prods_tbl.COUNT LOOP
    DECLARE
      lamt NUMBER := 0;
    BEGIN
      FOR k IN (
        SELECT SUM(quantity) qnt
        FROM (
          SELECT aop.quantity,
            aop.product_id prod_id,
            aor.cus_id,
            (SELECT epcv.descr FROM eba_prod_category_val epcv WHERE epcv.id = ecp.epc_1 AND epcv.epc_id = 1) Production
         FROM APT_ORDERS_PRODUCTS aop
            JOIN APT_ORDERS aor ON aor.id = aop.order_id
            JOIN eba_cust_products ecp ON aop.product_id = ecp.id
            JOIN eba_cust_customers ecc ON aor.cus_id = ecc.id
          WHERE
            ecc.status_id != 5 AND
            --aor.status_id != 24 AND
            aor.created_by NOT IN (4425, 239, 945, 1813, 598) AND
            aor.status_id NOT IN (24, 41) AND
            aor.invoice_number IS NULL AND
            aor.created >= TO_DATE('01/01/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
            --(SELECT epcv.descr FROM eba_prod_category_val epcv WHERE epcv.id = ecp.epc_1 AND epcv.epc_id = 1) IS NOT NULL AND
        )
        WHERE Production IS NOT NULL
        and prod_id = pProd --lcus_n_prods_tbl(i).product_id
        and cus_id = lcus_n_prods_tbl(i).cus_id
      ) 
      LOOP
        lamt := lamt + k.qnt;
      END LOOP;

      FOR j IN (select det_id,
                            cus_id,
                            prod_id,
                            order_id
                        from(
        SELECT aop.id det_id,
          aor.cus_id,
          aop.product_id prod_id,
          aor.id order_id,
          (SELECT epcv.descr FROM eba_prod_category_val epcv WHERE epcv.id = ecp.epc_1 AND epcv.epc_id = 1) Production
        FROM APT_ORDERS_PRODUCTS aop
          JOIN APT_ORDERS aor ON aor.id = aop.order_id
          JOIN eba_cust_products ecp ON aop.product_id = ecp.id
          JOIN eba_cust_customers ecc ON aor.cus_id = ecc.id
        WHERE
          ecc.status_id != 5 AND
          --aor.status_id != 24 AND
          aor.created_by NOT IN (4425, 239, 945, 1813, 598) AND
          aor.status_id NOT IN (24, 41) AND
          aor.invoice_number IS NULL AND
          aor.created >= TO_DATE('01/01/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
          --(SELECT epcv.descr FROM eba_prod_category_val epcv WHERE epcv.id = ecp.epc_1 AND epcv.epc_id = 1) IS NOT NULL AND
           )where Production is not null
            and prod_id = pProd --lcus_n_prods_tbl(i).product_id
            and cus_id = lcus_n_prods_tbl(i).cus_id
      ) LOOP
         if lwrh > 0 then
            select decode(sign(lamt - lwrh),-1,0,lamt - lwrh),lwrh - lamt into lamt,lwrh from dual;
            PIPE ROW (ADJUST_FINAL_ORDER_QNT_REC(lamt, pProd /*j.prod_id*/, j.cus_id, j.det_id));
         else
            PIPE ROW (ADJUST_FINAL_ORDER_QNT_REC(lamt, pProd /*j.prod_id*/, j.cus_id, j.det_id));
         end if;
      END LOOP;
    END;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;
```

**The View query:**

```
select
     sum_qnt,
     code,
     prod_id,
     description,
     wrh_gr,
     wrh_bg, 
     (select Amt from Table(fadjust_final_order_qnt(prod_id))where Prd = prod_id and Cus = cus_id and Id = det_id )/count(prod_id)over(partition by prod_id,cus_id) final_order_quantity,
     cat_id,
     cus_id,
     order_id
from
 (
    select  sum(quantity) sum_qnt,
            code ,
            prod_id,
            case when wrh_gr <= 0 then 0 when wrh_gr is null then 0 else wrh_gr end wrh_gr_v,
            case when wrh_bg <= 0 then 0 else wrh_bg end wrh_bg_v ,
            nvl(wrh_gr,0) wrh_gr,
            nvl(wrh_bg,0) wrh_bg,
            description,
            cus_id,
            order_id,
            cat_id,
            det_id
    from (
        SELECT  aop.id det_id,
                aor.id order_id,
                ecp.product_name code,
                nvl(ecp.global_descr, ecp.description) description,
                aop.quantity quantity,
                (Select epcv.descr from eba_prod_category_val epcv where epcv.id= ecp.epc_1 and epcv.epc_id=1 ) Production ,
                (select sum(gr.balance) from MV_PROD_WH_GR gr,  eba_products_mapping mg , eba_cust_products eg where gr.fitemgid = mg.gid and mg.product_id = eg.id and mg.origin = 'GR' and eg.id =ecp.id ) wrh_gr,
                (select sum(bg.balance) from MV_PROD_WH_BG bg,  eba_products_mapping mb , eba_cust_products eb where bg.fitemgid = mb.gid and mb.product_id = eb.id and mb.origin = 'BG' and eb.id =ecp.id ) wrh_bg,
                aop.product_id as prod_id,
                aor.cus_id cus_id,
                ecp.prod_cat_id cat_id
        FROM  APT_ORDERS_PRODUCTS aop ,
              APT_ORDERS aor,
              eba_cust_products ecp,
              eba_cust_customers ecc
        WHERE AOR.ID = AOP.ORDER_ID
          and aor.cus_id = ecc.id
          and ecc.status_id != 5
          and aop.product_id = ecp.id
          and aor.status_id!=24
          and aor.created_by not in (4425,239,945,1813,598)
          and aor.status_id not in (24,41)
          and aor.invoice_number is null
          and aor.created >= to_date('01/01/2022','dd/mm/yyyy')
        )where Production is not null
        group by code,
            wrh_gr,
            wrh_bg,
            description,
            prod_id,
            cat_id,
             cus_id,
             order_id,
             det_id
 )
```

I managed to improve it by adding *Bulk Collect Into* and by reducing *Select Into* clauses as much as possible. I also created some more indexes for the columns used in the *Where* clause of the queries. Pagination didn't work in the Interactive Report in APEX page, although I didn't believe it would do anything I gave it a try.

With all the above I gained 5 - 10 seconds.

- **Edit***
  So an example of a table is below:

```
  CREATE TABLE "CRM"."APT_ORDERS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CUS_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DELIVERY_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ALLOCATION" NUMBER, 
    "IS_LOCKED" NUMBER, 
    "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(800 BYTE), 
    "CREATED" DATE, 
    "CREATED_BY" NUMBER, 
    "UPDATED" DATE, 
    "UPDATED_BY" NUMBER, 
    "STATUS_ID" NUMBER, 
    "ORDER_KEY" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "DESTINATION" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE), 
    "PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE), 
    "ORDER_DATE" DATE, 
    "NEW_ARTWORKS" NUMBER, 
    "DELIVERY_TERMS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCTION_STOCK" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "ERP_ORDER_NUM" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ORDER_CONF_SENT" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ORDER_CONF_APPROVAL" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "PAYMENT_TERMS" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "DESIRED_LOADING_DATE" DATE, 
    "PACKAGING_MATERIALS" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ORDER_STATUS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "WAREHOUSE_DELIVERY_DATE" DATE, 
    "PREPAYMENT_BEFORE_LOADING" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "PREPAYMENT_STATUS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "LOADING_DATE" DATE, 
    "INVOICE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "INVOICE_VALUE" NUMBER, 
    "EXPECTED_DELIVERY_DATE" DATE, 
    "TRANSPORT_MEANS" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "TRANSPORT_COMPANY" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "TRANSPORT_COSTS" NUMBER, 
    "WAREHOUSE_DELIVERY_TERMS" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "WAREHOUSE_STATUS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SHIPPING_INSTRUCTIONS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CMR_TRANSP_COMP" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "BILL_OF_LADING" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "T2L" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "EURO_1" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "DECLARATION" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "RELEASED_CARGO" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SEAWAY_BILL" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "EXPORTS_COST" NUMBER, 
    "DOCUMENTS_UPLOADED" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "EMAIL_SENT_CUSTOMER" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ORIGINALS_SENT_BACKOFFICE" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ORIGINALS_SENT_CUSTOMER" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ORIGINALS_SENT_BANK" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "PENDING_ISSUES" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "IS_COMPLETED" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "EXPECTED_LOADING_DATE" DATE, 
    "RECEIVED_PAYMENT" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "EPR_CREATED_DATE" DATE, 
    "BANK_ORDER" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "HARD_UPDATE_STATUS" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "PAR_EXPORT" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ERP_NOTES" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE), 
    "OFFER_ID" NUMBER, 
    "PRODUCTION_STATUS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "DELETED_ERP" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "DELETED_ERP_AT" DATE, 
    "DELETED_ERP_BY" NUMBER, 
    "CUS_PRICELIST_ID" NUMBER, 
    "ORDER_DOCUMENT" NUMBER, 
    "TRANSPORTER_GID" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "INITIAL_DESIRED_LOADING_DATE" DATE, 
    "CONTACT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "PRE_ALLOCATION" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "ORIGIN" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "ORDER_TYPE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "PRICELIST_ID" NUMBER, 
    "PARENT_ORDER_ID" NUMBER, 
    "COMPLETE_ALLOCATION" NUMBER, 
    "LOADING_ALLOCATION" NUMBER, 
    "MORDER_KEY" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "IS_MATERIAL" NUMBER, 
    "COURIER_ID" NUMBER(12,0), 
    "MREC_ID" NUMBER(12,0), 
    "ACTUAL_DEL_DATE" DATE, 
    "PREP_PERC" NUMBER(12,0), 
    "CLOS_PAYM_PERC" NUMBER(12,0), 
    "PREP_WEEK" DATE, 
    "CLOS_PAYM_WEEK" DATE, 
    "PREPAYMENT_COMMENT" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "CLOS_PAY_COMMENT" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "ESTIMATED_LOADING_WEEK" NUMBER, 
    "IS_DELIVERED" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "EXPECTED_DELIVERY_DATE_NEW" DATE, 
    "WAREHOUSE_DELIVERY_DATE_BG" DATE, 
    "WAREHOUSE_DELIVERY_DATE_68" DATE, 
    "IS_FACTORING" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "PREPAYMENT_AMOUNT" NUMBER, 
    "CLOSING_PAYMENT_AMOUNT" NUMBER, 
    "IS_PAID" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "COMMENTS_OPERATIONS" VARCHAR2(800 BYTE), 
    "UNCERTAIN" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "PAYMENT_COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "EST_LOAD_WEEK_YEAR" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "PLANNED" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "CURR_ID" NUMBER, 
    "CURR_RATE" NUMBER, 
    "LOAD_TYPE" NUMBER, 
    "SM_MONTH" NUMBER, 
    "CURR_DATE" DATE, 
    "CHARGED_TRANS_COST" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "PAYMENT_DAYS" NUMBER, 
    "PAYMENT_GID" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE), 
    "POD_UPLOADED" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "ORDER_KINDS_ID" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_UK" UNIQUE ("ORDER_KEY")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CRM"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CRM"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_FK7" FOREIGN KEY ("COURIER_ID")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."APT_COURIERS" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_FK2" FOREIGN KEY ("UPDATED_BY")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."APPLICATION_USERS" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_FK8" FOREIGN KEY ("MREC_ID")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."APT_MAT_RECEIPTS" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_FK3" FOREIGN KEY ("CUS_ID")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."EBA_CUST_CUSTOMERS" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_FK4" FOREIGN KEY ("CUS_PRICELIST_ID")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."APT_PRICELISTS_HD" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_FK5" FOREIGN KEY ("PRICELIST_ID")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."APT_PRICELISTS_HD" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("CREATED_BY")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."APPLICATION_USERS" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EBA_SALES_CURRENCIES_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("CURR_ID")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."EBA_SALES_CURRENCIES" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_FK6" FOREIGN KEY ("PARENT_ORDER_ID")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."APT_ORDERS" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "APT_ORDERS_FK9" FOREIGN KEY ("ORDER_KINDS_ID")
      REFERENCES "CRM"."APT_ORDER_KINDS" ("ID") ENABLE
   ) ;
```

While I could just use `Create Table` with only the necessery columns and `Insert` only the required info it would take too much time. There are also a couple of Materilized views involved and it's just too much trouble for everyone I think. The question in the beginning and the answer given will suffice. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your queries all use:

```sql
SELECT aop.product_id as prod_id,
       (SELECT epcv.descr FROM eba_prod_category_val epcv WHERE epcv.id = ecp.epc_1 AND epcv.epc_id = 1) Production,
       something_else
FROM   APT_ORDERS_PRODUCTS aop
       JOIN APT_ORDERS aor ON aor.id = aop.order_id
       JOIN eba_cust_products ecp ON aop.product_id = ecp.id
       JOIN eba_cust_customers ecc ON aor.cus_id = ecc.id
WHERE  ecc.status_id != 5
--AND    aor.status_id != 24
AND     aor.created_by NOT IN (4425, 239, 945, 1813, 598)
AND     aor.status_id NOT IN (24, 41)
AND     aor.invoice_number IS NULL
AND     aor.created >= TO_DATE('01/01/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

All that differs is the `something_else` in the `SELECT` query.

Merge them all together. If you need to `SUM` values across the entire result set then use analytic functions.

```sql
SELECT aop.product_id as prod_id,
       (SELECT epcv.descr FROM eba_prod_category_val epcv WHERE epcv.id = ecp.epc_1 AND epcv.epc_id = 1) Production,
       -- First query
       SUM(
         GREATEST(
           NVL(
             (SELECT SUM(gr.balance)
              FROM   MV_PROD_WH_GR gr
                     INNER JOIN eba_products_mapping mg, eba_cust_products eg
                     ON mg.product_id = eg.id
              WHERE  gr.fitemgid = mg.gid
              AND    mg.origin = 'GR'
              AND    eg.id = ecp.id
             ),
             0
           ),
           0
         )
       ) OVER () AS wrh_gr,
       SUM(
         GREATEST(
           NVL(
             (SELECT SUM(bg.balance)
              FROM   MV_PROD_WH_BG bg
                     INNER JOIN eba_products_mapping mb
                     ON bg.fitemgid = mb.gid
                     INNER JOIN eba_cust_products eb
                     ON mb.product_id = eb.id
              WHERE  mb.origin = 'BG'
              AND    eb.id = ecp.id
             ),
             0
           ),
           0
         )
       ) OVER () AS wrh_bg,
       -- Second Query
       aor.cus_id,
       -- Third query
       aop.quantity
FROM   APT_ORDERS_PRODUCTS aop
       JOIN APT_ORDERS aor ON aor.id = aop.order_id
       JOIN eba_cust_products ecp ON aop.product_id = ecp.id
       JOIN eba_cust_customers ecc ON aor.cus_id = ecc.id
WHERE  ecc.status_id != 5
--AND    aor.status_id != 24
AND     aor.created_by NOT IN (4425, 239, 945, 1813, 598)
AND     aor.status_id NOT IN (24, 41)
AND     aor.invoice_number IS NULL
AND     aor.created >= TO_DATE('01/01/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Then you should be able to only run the query once.

You haven't provided any `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements for your sample data or what the expected output would be so trying to test the query is difficult (practically impossible?) so completing the rest of the refactoring process is left as an exercise to the OP. However, this should give you a pointer as to the direction you can take to combine all 3 queries into one and to not continually context-switch between SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm gonna test it out like this. I'm sorry I didn't provide more info there are several tables involved and the result set is close to 800 lines. I didn't think to get only several of them to show here. Now I know. I will edit and repost.